# JQuery select element val does not work on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a select box filled with options. When my function triggers, it should select the option that is passed. This works on all browsers except for Safari. currentSelectItem is a JQuery object storing the select.
Does anyone know why this does not work on Safari and how to make it work there?

```
<select name="options" id="myselect"> 
   <option value="2010">2010</option>
   <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>

$('#myselect').val(2011);
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]. Also, calling `val()` on something that is "containing all the options" sounds wrong; you'd call `.val()` on a jQuery object storing the `<select>` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it with some example code

Comment: It works for me in Safari 13.1.2: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3oLstxaf/

Comment: That code doesn't contain `currentSelectItem` anywhere. Also, the jQuery line does nothing, since the default value is the one of the first option, and you're using that in your `val()` call. Please double-check that the example code a) actually does something b) definitely doesn't work in Safari

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop('selected', true)`

```js
$('#select option[value="2"]').prop('selected',true);

// Or

$('#select').val(2).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Both methods work great on chrome, neither changes anything on Safari

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.prop('selected', true)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.